# Is there any way to force linker use function name rather than ordinal to import function?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

Create a DLL project,

```
void foo() {
    printf("foo");
}
```

def

```
LIBRARY
    EXPORTS
        foo @ 1
```

Create a client project,

```
void foo();
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The import table of the client executable.
[image: import table image]

The function name is missing in the import table.

Could you tell me, is there any way to force linker use function name?

Answer (score 0):

Create a second import library without the ordinals:

```
>type foo.names.def
LIBRARY foo.dll
EXPORTS
    foo

>lib /nologo /def:foo.names.def /machine:x86
   Creating library foo.names.lib and object foo.names.exp
```

Usage example:

```
>type test.c
void foo();

int main()
{
        foo();
        return 0;
}

>cl /nologo test.c /link foo.names.lib
test.c

>dumpbin /nologo /imports:foo.dll test.exe

Dump of file test.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Section contains the following imports:

    foo.dll
                40C108 Import Address Table
                410AA0 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                    0 foo
```

Contrast this with what you get when you use the "original" import library:

```
>cl /nologo test.c /link foo.lib
test.c

>dumpbin /nologo /imports:foo.dll test.exe

Dump of file test.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Section contains the following imports:

    foo.dll
                40C108 Import Address Table
                410AA0 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                      Ordinal     1
```

Comment: What if I could modify the library?

Comment: @Jichao:  I don't understand the question.  If you want the non-ordinal-importing lib to be named "foo.lib" then you can tell the lib command to build the library with that name.